# Apache with suPHP does not honor php_admin_value in vhost config

Tags: apache-2.4, suphp

I just found out that overriding php.ini settings in the vhost configuration does not work on Apache with suPHP.

The system is Ubuntu Server Edition 14.04 LTS and I installed Apache + PHP like this:

```
apt-get install apache2 apache2-mpm-prefork apache2-utils php5
```

Without changing any settings, the following vhost works out-of-the-box:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com

    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
    php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>
```

One can verify that the "open_basedir" setting is honored with phpinfo().

However, after installing suPHP and suExec:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-suphp apache2-suexec
a2enmod suexec
```

phpinfo() shows that the values are still those set in "/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini".
This is true not only for open_basedir, but for any setting I try to override with either `php_admin_value` or `php_value`.

Is there any way to make the above setup work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation at http://www.suphp.org/FAQ.html says suPHP doesn't support the php_admin_value directive.  You might be able to accomplish something similar using a custom php.ini file and the `suPHP_ConfigPath` directive though (see http://www.suphp.org/DocumentationView.html?file=apache/CONFIG).

Comment: Will the php.ini specified with `suPHP_ConfigPath` merge with `/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini`. or completely override it? That is, will values unset in `suPHP_ConfigPath` fall back to defaults or to the values set in `/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini`?

Comment: @matpen I'm not sure off the top of my head, but since you're already running it, just capture the output of `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` before and after using that directive, and paste the output into WinMerge to easily see what's changed.

Comment: @matpen Were you able to get this resolved?  If so, was this answer helpful?  Thanks

Comment: After researching and testing, I have concluded that the method you suggest is the only viable one. Unfortunately, the main configuration file `/etc/php5/cgi/php.ini` is ignored if the `suPHP_ConfigPath` is specified.